# Can't use my desktop on Ubuntu 19.10 after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I just upgraded a system to Ubuntu 19.10 from 18.04. I'm not able to boot into the desktop without seeing this notification:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.

If I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, I can see the desktop and can click on the icons but the notification will always block me from using the apps.

This is the dialog I am getting:

[image: screenshot of "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." screen]

Comment: Was upgrade successful or interrupted?

Comment: The upgrade path is tested from 18.04 to 18.10 (and 18.04 to 20.04 will be tested before it's launched), from 18.10 to 19.04, and from 19.04 to 19.10 - so skipping releases mean you're stepping outside of tested & supported upgrade paths and may encounter more difficulties (if not re-installed).  If you've added extensions, both use different gnome versions (3.28/3.34) so extensions can cause this b/c API/ABI's don't match (between extension/gnome+libs) due changes.

Answer (score 0):

While booting, before login, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This opens a console and once you log in into the console, try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once the execution is complete, reboot your system.

Comment: this did't work

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04