# ubuntu 19.10 GUI (gnome) will not load

Tags: server, gnome, login, 19.10

Been running ubuntu 19.10 for months. Suddenly, after a reboot today, I get this message after logging in via the gui greeter:

"Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."

Same screen shown in this post:
[Can't use my desktop on Ubuntu 19.10 after upgrading from 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187562/cant-use-my-desktop-on-ubuntu-19-10-after-upgrading-from-18-04)

The only option is to logout, which takes me back to the greeter screen.

I can login via TTY fine, fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try one of these:

- Create new user and verify you could login with it

  ```
  sudo adduser username && sudo usermod -aG sudo username
  ```
- Reinstall gnome:

  ```
  sudo apt purge *-gnome-*
  sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
  ```

User customization settings could be lost, but maybe user's customization is the cause of this buggy behavior.

Comment: MOST USEFUL. Thank you @Gryu. Since I could still login via TTY, I did so, and ran apt purge *-gnome-* . . . and then rebooted, expecting to see only a TTY session. Instead, the greeter came back, but this time in grey instead of the usual ubuntu purple. Successfully logged in. Display is all wonky now, but I can fix that... Will post results of install ubuntu-desktop. Thank you.

Comment: very interesting: after running apt install ubuntu-desktop and rebooting, I am back to the same original problem. Will purge again and continue probing.

Comment: After repeated tests... Reliably, purging *-gnome-* allowed me to get to *a* desktop, but with glitchy functionality, missing components, and no ability to look up applications via gui --- and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop took me back to problem state.
Ended up offloading all my data and wiping the machine clean, re-installing. 
Thanks much for your help, though. I learned a few things.

Comment: Ok. But have you tried new user creation and login with it after gnome reinstalling.

Comment: Going to try this next, @Gryu -- because after my rebuild... everything was working fine until I ran this command to remove amazon shit:
apt purge ubuntu-web-launchers. Immediately after running that, the amazon icon on the dock disappeared, but then the entire screen flickered, and firefox crashed. I rebooted, and came back to the original problem that started this all. 
SO: now going to properly follow your entire suggestion.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I'll try to reproduce it when will be at home

Comment: Grrreat. Will post more info as I get it. Also: it's 19.10 server

Comment: I tried removing that and reboot. Nothing changed. I use Ubuntu Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

I also aff a problem with gnome not working.
I solved it with following commands :

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Note : gnome desktop manager is 'gdm', not 'lightdm', but I read it is about to be replaced by lightgdm ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58528/whats-the-difference-between-gdm-and-lightdm))

Answer (score 0):

be careful and don't forget about changes to your desktop manager!  Reconfigure it via sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3  . With all the problems in past with gdm etc.... people need to know simple fix for results encountered.  Been there, done that!